# What does PO stand for in this context?

Tags: meaning

The man is a former inmate and is looking for a room to rent. The woman asks him:

-So, is this through you PO?

-No, ma'am. I don't have a PO. I was exonerated of my charges.

What does PO stand for?

Comment: Please add literary context to this question. This site is for literature and generic English-language questions are off-topic.

Comment: Where is this quoted exchange from? Please [edit] to indicate the source.

Comment: [I downvoted because being unresponsive to requests for clarification is not helpful.](http://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A parole officer or a probation officer is a person working for the court system who supervises criminals upon their release from jail or prison if their sentences have been reduced or sometimes those who have been convicted on a lesser charge.

In this case, the lessor (person whose owns the rental or represents the landlord) is assuming that because this person is a former inmate, they have a parole or probation officer working with them to establish housing. This former inmate does not because when one is exonerated (recognized as being not guilty), they can leave the court system as a free person who does not need supervised.

Comment: Please don't answer off-topic questions